# blockUI compatibility issue with IE11?

Tags: javascript, ajax, blockui

While the following piece of code works both in Chrome and FF, I can't get it work in ie11. Now tried even with ie8 and it's working just fine... 
I wonder if anyone else having similar issues with blockUI on ie11?

I am using jQuery 1.8.3, Bootstrap 3.1.1
Error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'BlockUI'"

```
function onLinkedInAuth() {
    IN.API.Profile("me").result(displayProfiles);
}

function displayProfiles(profiles) {
    member = profiles.values[0];
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://indigopages.net/main/liauth/" + member.id ,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.blockUI();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.unblockUI();
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So what exactly goes wrong? Have you checked the developer console for errors? What version of the software are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.8.3, Bootstrap 3.1.1 
Error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'BlockUI'"

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the ie did the trick (Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset).